# problem with an if statement

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

For some reason the argument I pass to my if statement is not true for even though it should be heres my code:

```
    if (currentAttribute == cBusName)
    {
        NSLog(@"currentAttribute == cBusName");
    }
```

current attribute and cBusName are both NSMutableStrings an both equal "1" but the NSLog never outputs the string in the console is there something I am missing???

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `==` operator is comparing that those objects are the same object (IE they point to the same address in memory), not that their values are the same.

Try

```
if ([currentAttribute isEqualToString: cBusName])
{
    NSLog(@"currentAttribute == cBusName");
}
```

which compares the *values* of the two strings, not their location in memory.

Comment: For more details on this see: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_String_Objects_in_Objective-C#Comparing_Strings

Comment: damn, you beat me to the punch... +1

Comment: Haha for once it was me who typed it first. I'm usually in you're guys positions.

Answer (score 0):

> String objects cannot be compared
>   using the equality (==) operator. The
>   reason for this is that any attempt to
>   perform a comparison this way will
>   simply compare whether the two string
>   objects are located at the same memory
>   location. Let's take a look at this
>   via an example:via an example:

from http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_String_Objects_in_Objective-C, search for Comparing Strings